# The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.8

I get the following error when publishing my web app to a local folder.

> The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found

I checked the [registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) and I do have 4.8 installed.  Visual Studio Enterprise specifically recommended to me, upon opening the solution that, that I should update the target framework to 4.8 and I agreed.

VS then set the compilation targetFramework attribute to 4.8 (from 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

I double-checked my installation of visual studio. I opened visual studio installer and it said there was an update.  I applied the update, which took a long time.  I opened the solution again, published, and viola!  I'm not sure what happened, but that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was to add **FrameworkPathOverride** as a parameter along with your MSBuild commands.

**So basically the command would look like this:**

bat ‘”C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe” MySolutionName.sln /**p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\”Any CPU\” –p:FrameworkPathOverride=”C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5″‘**

Notes:

1. Make sure you have the required SDK installed on your agent and if
   not then install it first, no need to install the whole VS 2015 –
   just SDK should work
2. Note that the path may change in your case. I just paste the path
   which worked for me
3. Also, this is not a full and final solution to allow your regular
   .Net project to build with the latest VS 2017 tooling, it is just a
   solution to the above error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, installed the SDK, no change, still same error. Shutting down and restarting Visual Studio worked for me.